# SQL looping over data to find maximum value (special case)

Tags: mysql, sql

OK. I have database which is made from data used in TRAVIAN game. I have 200000 rows, so I want to reduce it for Excel analysis.

```
x   y   village player alliance population  date
27 -41  h1      h       S       35          2009-12-23
27 -41  h1      h       S       56          2009-12-24
27 -41  h1      h       S       60          2009-12-25
27 -41  h1      h       S       89          2009-12-26
```

These are just some of the important atributes in table. There is a lot of other entries for each village every time when player is logged into system. So you can see the population growing per each village. I just want to write an sql statement which returns me only entry where maximum population of the village is. (for each village of course).

I wrote something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM x_world
GROUP BY village
HAVING population = max(population)
```

In theory i want to loop over each village and search for its biggest population entry and take just that one. I want to do this for each village. This is how i will also a total number of villages.

Comment: please copy that data somewhere else and make a new row after each date. (don't know how to do this here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query using joins. It is much faster then dependant subqueries.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM x_world as xr
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
                x,
                MAX(population)
        FROM x_world as xr
        GROUP BY x 
) as xt ON xt.x = xr.x
GROUP BY village
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks:) It works but now i have two x columns, so i want to drop the previous column.

Comment: what do you mean by two x columns? Can you explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM x_world
GROUP BY village
HAVING SUM(population)=
  (SELECT MAX(a.population)
  FROM
    (SELECT village,SUM(population) population FROM x_world GROUP BY village
    ) a
  )
```

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0253/3)

Comment: I am befuddled by how someone could upvote an answer that is clearly wrong.  The inner query is getting the sum of populations for a village, which makes no sense because of the time component.  It is then taking the overall max of this value, and comparing it to the sum.  The question pretty clearly wants the maximum population per village (" I just want to write an sql statement which returns me only entry where maximum population of the village is. (for each village of course)."

Comment: thanks for your feedback. By the way i didnt include time component in my sql demo. See my demo. OP can just add time component.

Comment: . . There *is* a time component.  The sample data is for one village over time.  Your query is sort of answering:  "Which village has the maximum inhabitant-days?"  I have no problem with misunderstanding a question (which happens to me a bit too often); I'm surprised at the upvote.

Comment: OP wants an idea, how to do this kind of problems. We shouldnt exactly tell them everything. There should be a chance for them to learn also. If you are not convinced with upvote then downvote it. No issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this:

```
select *
from x_world w
where population = (select max(population) from x_world w2 where w2.village = w.village)
```

Caution:  This will return multiple rows when a village has more than one maximum population.

In practice, this can be fixed in MySQL by doing:

```
select *
from x_world w
where population = (select max(population) from x_world w2 where w2.village = w.village)
group by village
```

However, this makes use of Hidden Columns, so the columns are not *guaranteed* to come from the same row (although in practice they seem to).

To get one row, it is helpful to have an id.  From your example, date would work for this, producing a query something like:

```
select *
form x_world w join
     (select village, max(population) as maxpop,
             substring_index(group_concat(date_format(date, '%Y%m%d'), ',') as maxdate
      from x_world
     ) wmax
     on w.village = wmax.village and
        w.population = wmax.population and
        date_format(w.date, '%Y%m%d') = wmax.date
```